# Array persistance inside allocated nested types

Tags: fortran

I am trying to build a nested type structure with the following declaration:

```
TYPE T_ORCH_DISCR
   REAL(r_std), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION (:,:)   :: simp ! 
   REAL(r_std), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION (:,:,:) :: disc ! 
CONTAINS
   PROCEDURE :: initialize
END TYPE T_ORCH_DISCR
```

`t_orch_discr` initialization:

```
SUBROUTINE initialize(this, kjpindex, argsec, discrdim)
  CLASS(T_ORCH_DISCR), INTENT(inout)        :: this
  INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in)              :: kjpindex
  INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in)              :: argsec
  INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in), OPTIONAL    :: discrdim

  INTEGER(i_std) :: ier

  has_discretization = .FALSE.
  IF (PRESENT(discrdim)) THEN
    has_discretization = discrdim
  ENDIF

  IF (.NOT. has_discretization) THEN
    ALLOCATE (this%simp(kjpindex,argsec),stat=ier)
  ELSE
    ALLOCATE (this%disc(kjpindex,argsec,discrdim),stat=ier)
  ENDIF
END SUBROUTINE initialize
```

Either `simp` or `disc` will be allocated, but they won't be allocated both at the same time.

And:

```
TYPE T_MC_HYDRO
  TYPE(T_ORCH_DISCR) :: mc_layh
  TYPE(T_ORCH_DISCR) :: mcl_layh
  TYPE(T_ORCH_DISCR) :: soilmoist
CONTAINS
  PROCEDURE :: initialize
END TYPE T_MC_HYDRO
```

`t_mc_hydro` initialization:

```
SUBROUTINE initialize(this, kjpindex, nslm, nstm, nvm)
 CLASS(T_MC_HYDRO), INTENT(inout)     :: this
 INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in)           :: kjpindex
 INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in)           :: nslm
 INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in), OPTIONAL :: nstm
 INTEGER(i_std), INTENT(in), OPTIONAL :: nvm

 INTEGER(i_std) :: ier

 has_discretization = .FALSE.
 IF (PRESENT(nvm) .AND. PRESENT(nstm)) THEN
   has_discretization = .TRUE.
 ENDIF

 IF (has_discretization) THEN
   CALL this%mc_layh%initialize(kjpindex, nslm, nstm)
   CALL this%mcl_layh%initialize(kjpindex, nslm, nstm)
   CALL this%soilmoist%initialize(kjpindex, nslm, nvm)
 ELSE
   CALL this%mc_layh%initialize(kjpindex, nslm)
   CALL this%mcl_layh%initialize(kjpindex, nslm)
   CALL this%soilmoist%initialize(kjpindex, nslm)
 ENDIF
END SUBROUTINE initialize
```

Declared in a global module scope somewhere else:

```
TYPE(T_MC_HYDRO), SAVE :: t_mc_hydrol
```

The intention is to make `t_mc_hydrol` persistent when the module goes out of scope. But the current code does not produce such effect. I am struggling to understand the best approach.

**Update**:

In order to reproduce the issue:

Main program:

```
PROGRAM unittests
  USE types_tests

  IMPLICIT NONE

  TYPE(T_MC_HYDRO), SAVE :: torch_test
  INTEGER(i_std), PARAMETER :: kjpindex=20, nslm=10

  CALL torch_test%initialize(kjpindex, nslm)
  CALL types_tests_init(torch_test)
  CALL types_tests_main(torch_test)
END PROGRAM unittests
```

Intermediate module used in the original code:

```
MODULE types_tests
  USE ioipsl_para
  USE type_moisture_content_hydro

  IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE types_tests_init(torch_test)
    TYPE(T_MC_HYDRO), INTENT(out) :: torch_test

    torch_test%mc_layh%simp = 22.0
    torch_test%mcl_layh%simp = 23.0
  END SUBROUTINE types_tests_init

  SUBROUTINE types_tests_main(torch_test)
    TYPE(T_MC_HYDRO), INTENT(out) :: torch_test
    INTEGER(i_std) :: ji, jl

    DO ji=1, 20 ! kjpindex ! 20
    DO jl=1, 10 ! nslm
      torch_test%mc_layh%simp(ji,jl) = 25.0 !! <--- code fails here
      torch_test%mcl_layh%simp(ji,jl) = 24.0
    ENDDO
    ENDDO
  END SUBROUTINE types_tests_main

END MODULE types_tests
```

Error code:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
unittests.exe      00000000005B3E14  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.17.s  00002B1D3DDE35E0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
unittests.exe      0000000000410F9B  types_tests_mp_ty          78  types_tests.f90
unittests.exe      000000000040CEB5  MAIN__                     64  unittests.f90
unittests.exe      000000000040C95E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002B1D3E215C05  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
unittests.exe      000000000040C869  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
srun: error: irene1124: task 0: Exited with exit code 174
```

Comment: `TYPE(T_MC_HYDRO), INTENT(out) :: torch_test` makes the reference later in that subroutine to a dummy argument (with `intent(out)`) rather than a module/"global" variable.  I'm inclined to vote to close as a typo, or is there something you don't understand about arguments?

Comment: I did miss the point about intent (out) and its interaction with type statement

Comment: As stated by @francescalus, by changing the arguments definition to INTENT(inout) worked.